# Insert value in web page text field from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension which copies data from clipboard and using Ctrl+m key pastes values one by one in a text field which is in the extension itself. Now using same hotkey as above(ctrl+m) i want the text to pasted in a text field which is in web page. Below is code snippet and screen shot

```
        if(event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'm'){
            var shiftedVal=temp.shift(); //temp contains clipboard data
            if(shiftedVal!=null){
            //document.activeElement.value=shiftedVal; 
            document.getElementById("textfield").value=shiftedVal;
            }else{
                alert("No more values. Que is Empty");
            }
```

I tried to use both document.activeElement and document.getElementById but as soon as i click on text field in web page it lost focus and does not paste any value. See the screenshot below
[image]

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: I am using that only and I am able to fetch the values from clipboard but what I am struggling here is to pass those values in a text field located on a web page

Comment: The example I've linked shows how to set the value. It's not related to clipboard.

Comment: It seems you need to pass the value to content script by using chrome runtime message passing api.

Comment: @Ashik You got any example/link

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

`index.js` or `popup.js`

```
let copybtn = document.getElementById("btn")
let txt_area = document.getElementById("tarea")

copybtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { type: "from_index", message: txt_area.value})
})
```

`content.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        if(request.type === "from_index"){
            // get the target textarea and assign value
            document.querySelector('td[class="exampleDisplay"]>textarea').value = request.message
            sendResponse({})
        }
        return true
    }
)
```

Hope it helps.